# How to upload files to GCS from a python script in GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload a file into GCS, but I'm running into a permission issue which I'm not sure how to resolve. Reading a file from a bucket in GCS doesn't seem to be an issue. However, I'm getting issues for upload.

```
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('fda-drug-label-data')
blob = bucket.get_blob(f'fda-label-doc-links.csv')
bt = blob.download_as_string()
s = str(bt, 'utf-8')
s = StringIO(s)
df = pd.read_csv(s)

df_doc_links = list(df['Link'])

a = pd.DataFrame([len(df_doc_links)])
a.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('fda-drug-label-data')
blob = bucket.blob('test.csv')
blob.upload_from_filename('test.csv')
```

This is the message I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1567, in upload_from_file
    if_metageneration_not_match,   File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1420, in _do_upload
    if_metageneration_not_match,   File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1098, in _do_multipart_upload
    response = upload.transmit(transport, data, object_metadata, content_type)   File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/requests/upload.py", line 108, in transmit
    self._process_response(response)   File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_upload.py", line 109, in _process_response
    _helpers.require_status_code(response, (http_client.OK,), self._get_status_code)   File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_helpers.py", line 96, in require_status_code
    *status_codes google.resumable_media.common.InvalidResponse: ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPSta tus.OK: 200>) During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "scrape.py", line 134, in <module>
    blob.upload_from_filename('test.csv')   File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1655, in upload_from_filename
    if_metageneration_not_match=if_metageneration_not_match,   File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 1571, in upload_from_file
    _raise_from_invalid_response(exc)   File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 2620, in _raise_from_invalid_response
    raise exceptions.from_http_status(response.status_code, message, response=response) google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/fda-drug-label-da ta/o?uploadType=multipart: ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permission to upload to the data in your service account.Go to IAM and Admin section and under service accounts assign permission role to your account.After that generate the KEY again.

Comment: You don't need to re-download the key. Any permissions you add to the service account automatically get picked up by an existing key.

Comment: @GabeWeiss is this applicable for when we authenticate via json file?

Comment: Correct. If you, when you created the service account, hit "Create key" and downloaded the json file, that bearer token (the json file) is just a key pointing back to the service account. So any roles/permissions you add to the service account will automatically get picked up by the json file.

Comment: It's a very bad advice! Service account key file are a nightmare for the security. It's a simple file, that you can copy, send by email or even commit into a GIt (maybe public). In addition, you have to store it securely (it's your secret for the authentication) and Google recommend to rotate this file at least every 90 days! If you are on your local environment, simply perform a `gcloud auth application-default login` for using your own credential in the tests. If it's on GCP, let me know on which service for more help. If it's outside GCP, it's the only case where you need a key file!!!